# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in wordpress website

Tags: jquery, wordpress

> i am getting this error while loading the wordpress webiste. it stop the working of the revolution slider.i am using the total_child theme of wordpress. any help.?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // CUSTOM AJAX CONTENT LOADING FUNCTION
            var ajaxRevslider = function(obj) {

                // obj.type : Post Type
                // obj.id : ID of Content to Load
                // obj.aspectratio : The Aspect Ratio of the Container / Media
                // obj.selector : The Container Selector where the Content of Ajax will be injected. It is done via the Essential Grid on Return of Content

                var content = "";

                data = {};

                data.action = 'revslider_ajax_call_front';
                data.client_action = 'get_slider_html';
                data.token = 'ef60422c21';
                data.type = obj.type;
                data.id = obj.id;
                data.aspectratio = obj.aspectratio;

                // SYNC AJAX REQUEST
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"http://christiansteven.com/en/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:data,
                    async:false,
                    success: function(ret, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        if(ret.success == true)
                            content = ret.data;                             
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                });

                 // FIRST RETURN THE CONTENT WHEN IT IS LOADED !!
                 return content;                         
            };
```

Comment: Well, is jQuery included? You posted a jQuery function, so if jQuery isn't included and you try to run it, naturally you're going to get *jQuery is not defined*.

Comment: /en/ (line 1350, col 6)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: yes jquery is added at the top of the page inside the head tag rom google CDN.<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js' defer='defer'></script>

Answer (score 1):

On line 47 of your page, you are loading jQuery and specifying the `defer` attribute:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://christiansteven.com/en/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js' defer='defer'></script>
```

The defer attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.

Slightly further down in your code, you have this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>try{jQuery.noConflict();}catch(e){};</script>
```

When this line of JS is parsed, jQuery doesn't exist, as you previously specified `defer`

If you remove the `defer`, you will see that your slider gives you a different error message that you can (allegedly) solve via the plugin settings in WP.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress already includes a copy of jQuery. Enqueuing the jQuery script in the head (using the WordPress enqueue script function) would make it available for your code.

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
```

Also, to enqueue other scripts that require jQuery, you can use this same syntax specifying "jquery" in the array of required scripts:

```
wp_enqueue_script('myScriptName', '/pathToScript/myScriptFile.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
```

[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is the wp_enqueue_script function reference.